# How do I extend a Bootstrap class in {less}?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm obviously new with less so bare with the newbie question. I'm trying to make a common CSS that I can use throughout my site but is using Bootstrap. For instance, I want to use Bootstrap's panel class. Currently we are using the ".panel-primary" class in several places. However, if we decided we wanted to use a different color like ".panel-default" I don't want to have to go to all my pages that might have a few panels on them to make the change. Instead I'm hoping to create a common CSS class that would inherit the Bootstrap class so I would have only one location to make the change.

It was suggested that I look at using less or SAAS for this and from the basics I've seen I think less is all I would need.

I'm using an ASP.Net MVC project so I used NuGet to install "dotless". I then changed my css file to be site.less and it looks as though that's working. Now I'm trying to use the extend to do what I want but I'm obviously missing something because the CSS is not applying the Bootstrap class.

Here is my the Bootstrap class I'm originally using.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            Available Stations
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.DropDownList("City", Model.CityList, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        @Html.Raw("&nbsp;")
        <input type=submit name=submit value="Set Station" class="btn btn-info">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my attempt to use less and apply it to my page.

```
.vtc-panel{
    &:extend(.panel);
    &:extend(.panel-primary);
}

<div class="vtc-panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            Available Stations
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.DropDownList("City", Model.CityList, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        @Html.Raw("&nbsp;")
        <input type=submit name=submit value="Set Station" class="btn btn-info">
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Here are some other things I've tried but still can't get it to work.

First off I thought maybe it's not seeing the Bootstrap file so I did an @import at the top of my less file. That seem to work to include the Bootstrap but I then tried the following change to the css class and it's still not applying the Bootstrap styling.

```
@import (inline) '../Content/bootstrap.min.css';

.vtc-panel:extend(.panel, .panel-primary){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So after some more digging around I finally got this to work. I'm passing it along so that it will hopefully help someone else. This assumes you have LESS install and setup.

First thing that needs to be done is to change your Bootstrap file over to less. Rename `bootstrap.min.css` to `bootstrap.min.less`. This puts the bootstrap through the LESS compile engine.

Then import the bootstrap file in your main LESS file. I put this at the top of my site.less file.

```
@import (inline) '../Content/bootstrap.less';
```

Then in my site.less file I added a class called "vtc-panel" and inherited "panel" class from bootstrap.

```
.vtc-panel{
    .panel;
    .panel-primary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included the Bootstrap files as LESS files, and not as CSS file.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. It actually caused all of the Bootstrap classes to not work. Kind of weird because I would have thought that changing it to a less file wouldn't have made a difference either way since ultimately less should have compiled it all down to CSS.